# MongoDb: Aggregation using Groovy language

Tags: mongodb, groovy, aggregation-framework, fiware, fiware-knowage

Iam using groovy scripting under SpagoBI. I want to use aggregation.
I want for example to execute the following aggregation:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : { day: { $dayOfMonth: "$recvTime" } }

        }
      }
   ]
)
```

I tried:

```
DBObject projectFields = new BasicDBObject('$dayOfMonth',"recvTime");
DBObject project=new BasicDBObject('$project',projectFields)

DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id",project);

DBObject group = new BasicDBObject('$group', groupFields);

iterable = db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate(group)
```

I got this error:

```
An unexpected error occured while executing dataset: { "serverUsed" : "192.168.1.160:27017" , "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$project'" , "code" : 15999 , "ok" : 0.0}
```

Any ideas?

Updates:
the query executed in Mongo shell

```
db['cygnus_/kurapath_enocean_power_enocean'].aggregate(
...    [
...       {
...         $group : {
...            _id : { day: { $dayOfMonth: "$recvTime" } }
...         }
...       }
...    ]
... );
{ "_id" : { "day" : 9 } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 8 } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 7 } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 4 } }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 3 } }
```

the data stored in mongo db:

```
db['cygnus_/kurapath_enocean_power_enocean'].find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55e81e9631d7791085668331"), "recvTime" : ISODate("2015-09-03T10:19:02Z"), "attrName" : "power", "attrType" : "string", "attrValue" : "2085.0" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55e81e9631d7791085668332"), "recvTime" : ISODate("2015-09-03T10:19:02Z"), "attrName" : "power", "attrType" : "string", "attrValue" : "2085.0" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55e81e9831d7791085668333"), "recvTime" : ISODate("2015-09-03T10:19:04Z"), "attrName" : "power", "attrType" : "string", "attrValue" : "2077.0" }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error, the aggregation is not expecting the **`$project`** operator so you should change the `projectFields` and `project` variables to show the actual pipeline expressions i.e.

```
DBObject dateFields = new BasicDBObject("$dayOfMonth", "$recvTime");
DBObject dateObject = new BasicDBObject("day", dateFields);

DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", dateObject);
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject('$group', groupFields);

iterable = db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate(group);
```

Comment: I tried your code but I got a new error :( :
`An unexpected error occured while executing dataset: No such property: dayOfMonth for class: Script119 ` when I tried `DBObject dateFields = new BasicDBObject('$dayOfMonth', "recvTime");` I got `
An unexpected error occured while executing dataset: { "serverUsed" : "192.168.1.160:27017" , "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type String to Date" , "code" : 16006 , "ok" : 0.0}`

Comment: You forgot to include the `$` in your `"recvTime"` field, so change your line `DBObject dateFields = new BasicDBObject('$dayOfMonth', "recvTime")` to `DBObject dateFields = new BasicDBObject('$dayOfMonth', "$recvTime")`.

Comment: I updated the code to `DBObject dateFields = new BasicDBObject('$dayOfMonth', "$recvTime")` but I got this error `An unexpected error occured while executing dataset: No such property: recvTime for class`, if I updated to `DBObject dateFields = new BasicDBObject('$dayOfMonth', '$recvTime');` I got an empty result set

Comment: Looks like the latter (with single quotes) works, can't get much inference from the empty result set without some sample data. Is the `recvTime` field of ISODate type?

Comment: I updated my question with some data and with the query executed on the Mongo shell, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In SpagoBI you have 2 ways to create a dataset of type MongoDB:
1)  use a dataset of type Query and use JS language
2)  use a dataset of type java class and write your code in java
For solution 1 you should create a dataset of type query, select a datasource MongoDB and write on the field QUERY the query in js following the specification written here (http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_server/data_set#HQueryDataSet28Mongo29)

The button “Edit script” is used to modify the query string and you can find some tip in the wiki. So if the query is SQL you can use a js o groovy script to change the query string (for example apply some logic to create parameters or table names)

You can express your query in this way:

```
Var query = db.myCollection.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : { day: { $dayOfMonth: "$recvTime" } }

        }
      }
   ]
)
```